# PDO insert into one column

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Really idk whats wrong here every time I try to insert into 1 signal column?

Database connected very well, table name is `stad`, and it contains two columns `id` AI PRIMARY and `name` unique

```
<?php
    @$submit = $_POST['submit'] ;
    @$stadName = $_POST['stadName'];
    if(isset($submit)){
       if(!$stadName){
         echo "Error" ;
       }else{
         $sql = 'INSERT INTO stad name VALUES :name';
         $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
         $stmt->execute(['name' =>  $stadName]);
         echo "DONE" ;
       }
    }
    ?>
```

connection file

```
<?php
$serv = '127.0.0.1';
$user = 'root';
$pass = 'root';
$dbname = 'akfoot';

// db base connection
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:dbname='.$dbname.';host='.$serv.'; charset=utf8',$user,$pass);

?>
```

Database:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing brackets around your column list and your value list (even if it's just one column, those brackets are required):

```
$sql = 'INSERT INTO stad (name) VALUES (:name)';
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute(['name' =>  $stadName]);
```

Comment: it didn't work ;( 
for that reason I was trying different stuff

Comment: `$stmt->execute(['name' =>  $stadName]);` this should be like `$stmt->execute([':name' =>  $stadName]);` I guess

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
include "connect.php" ;

@$submit = $_POST['submit'] ;
@$stadName = $_POST['stadName'];
   if(isset($submit)){
if(!$stadName){
   echo "error" ;
}else{
   $sql = 'INSERT INTO stad (name) VALUES (:name)';
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute(['name' =>  $stadName]);
echo "done" ;
}
}
?>
```

[image: data base]
this is the connection file

```
<?php
$serv = '127.0.0.1';
$user = 'root';
$pass = 'root';
$dbname = 'akfoot';

// db base connection
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:dbname='.$dbname.';host='.$serv.'; charset=utf8',$user,$pass);

?>
```

Answer (score -1):

The Problem was the type of data is Arabic and me I used another encoding type and I have to use UTF8 bin instead of latino

THANK YOU GUYS JUST KNOW WHAT MISTAKE THAT I MADE